# How to reset track changes in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Studio and I really like the [track changes feature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/04/14/track-changes-in-the-editor-vstipedit0048.aspx):

After a while, the files I am currently editing are completely green. When it happens I want to clear all the marks.

I found three ways but they are not as simple as I would like:

- Close and reopen Visual Studio.
- Close and reopen all files.
- Open the option dialog, uncheck the feature, reopen the dialog and check the feature back.
  [image]

Is there a magic shortcut ?

Comment: I was fairly certain that on the second save, the green marks would disappear... Is that not the case?

Comment: @CodyGray not with Visual Studio 2012 at least.

Comment: No shortcut, you could write a macro to close the edit window and open it again for the same file.

Comment: @HansPassant Macros were removed in VS2012.

Comment: Maybe he should not use the [visual-studio-2010] tag then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have just published simple Visual Studio Extension named [Clear Tracked Changes](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/90322f25-e1c7-43fb-8695-b190ac87664d) which does the job. Basically it toggles the `TOOLS -> Options -> Text Editor -> Track Changes` setting, which clears the tracked changes as a side effect.

Comment: Great Work! Just one note for the french users, the shortcut is in Outils.ClearTrackedChanges.

Comment: This was a great extension. Could you update it to install with VS 2013? (I'm on update 4, if that matters.)

Comment: @goodeye Done :). Ping me if you find any problems. By the way, the code is availvable on github here: [ClearTrackedChanges](https://github.com/bsivanov/ClearTrackedChanges), and I accept pull requests!

Answer (score 4):

To reset changes only for the current document, you can use the [Clear tracked changes](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/commands.html#ClearChanges) command for Visual Commander.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to my knowledge to remove the green indicator. However, you can essentially disable the saved color entirely, leaving only the yellow unsaved marker or no marker at all.

Under Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors. Set 'Show Settings for' to 'Text Editor'
Scroll down in Display Items for 'Track Changes after save'. Change this to whatever color you like.

[image: Track Changes after save]

If you want to disable it, set Item Background color to be the same color as Item Background for Plain Text.

I, too, don't want my entire sidebar to turn green. So, I use this to have the yellow indicator on the un-saved changes, and saving turns the entire column back to black.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/) for a while now. It links the Track changes feature to the modification since the last commit in subversion. For those using [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/), it could be one of the most useful alternative. Basically, you don't need to track the changes manually: it is done automatically when you commit your files.