# How to reset 'Track changes' in Visual Studio without closing/opening the file?

Tags: visual-studio

Is it possible to reset **'Track changes'** for a file without closing/opening the file?

If yes, how?

---

By **'Tracking changes'** I mean the green/yellow little bars on the left side of the text editor (image below).

[image: Tracking Changes]

Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768233/how-to-reset-track-changes-in-visual-studio

Comment: Thanks @SergeyVlasov

Answer (score 0):

A cheating solution is to turn off 'Track changes' and turn it on again. The only side effect is that it removes tracking changes for all files.

I also found this extension [Clear Tracked Changes](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bsivanov.ClearTrackedChanges) which does the same thing.